# SQL Server select fixed value every second row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I’m creating a process in SSIS that imports data that we receive from a vendor and import it into a table. After the imports completes it moves on to the next step to create a fixed width file to prepare to send to another location for processing. I have the first line parsed out perfectly but I need to add a second line using a fixed value of 99 between each row as a trailer record.

Current rows:

```
Col1       Col2      Col3   Col4          Col5                     
C1     AHS    X000501787    0477802       20180410      
C1     AHS    Y000501832    0477805       20180410      
C1     AHS    Z000501844    0477803       20180410      
C1     AHS    E000501801    0477804       20180410
```

Desired results below:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3          Col4          Col5                     
C1     AHS    X000501787    0477802       20180410   
99
C1     AHS    Y000501832    0477805       20180410   
99
C1     AHS    Z000501844    0477803       20180410      
99
C1     AHS    E000501801    0477804       20180410
```

Any input appreciated!

Comment: First Question is what is reasons you need to do this?

Comment: I'm parsing the select into a flat file and the #99 is the trailer record after each line.

Comment: How are you creating the fixed witdh file?  are you exporting i tline by line?  You can loop through your records from the table and inset a row, then insert your row with 99, then loop again

Comment: This code is part of an SSIS package that I built. I'm using fixed width in my flat file connection manager. I got almost everything to work the way I need it but having issues getting this part to do what I need it to do. I sort of got the below to work but it doesn't quite do what I need it to do: SELECT other columns...,
CAST(Col5 AS varchar(100)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '99' AS Col6
FROM..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're going to run into is that you are attempting to build a mulit-record output and SSIS doesn't do that. It expects that the format of each column in each row is the same.

The two approaches I've seen people use is to either concatenate all the columns together per row, define the format within SSIS as a one column file and handle all the string formatting in your query. That's an awfully fragile way of doing things. This approach though is required if you're building out truly different lines. i.e.

```
ABBBBCCCCCCC
FFGGHHHHIIIIJJJ
```

The other approach would be to make each column string and then for your "off" rows, just don't provide a value.

The other problem you will run into is how do you define your grouping. Yours is a simpler situation in that it's just "every row". Again, you're either looking at doing it in a query or using a Script Component in an asynchronous fashion since 1 row in = 2 rows out.